# git new branch commit : new files not found on status or to commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, bitbucket

My team is using [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for managing our team project which is developed on Visual Studio 2013. And it is simple and easy to maintain our work.

Last day I created a `new branch` of my project on git named `version2`.

```
$ git branch version2
$ git branch
  * master
    version2
$git checkout test

$ git branch
  master
* version2
```

So now the project is on the `version2` branch. And the project local location remains the same.

I am facing the following issue,

> If we are adding a new file and check the git status, there is nothing
>   to show for commit. But if we modify any existing file, which works
>   fine or able to commit. Only newly added files are missing.

What is the reason? What have I missed?

Comment: try git add, maybe it is in the .gitignore and for some reason filtered out in the git status

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `.gitginore`?

Comment: @Joost how to use gitginore command ?

Comment: It's not a command, it's a file. Try `cat .gitignore` to see the contents.

Comment: @Joost ok . I will check

Comment: @Joost there is nothing there. A tagline by microsoft and my project path like '/ProjectName'

Comment: That's *not* nothing. If your project path is in there, everything that is in your project is ignored from being listed as untracked. Try `mv .gitignore .gitignore.bak` to temporarly disable it, and see if that fixes your issue. Then swap the arguments to restore.

Comment: Yes . You are correct. Feel bad for my ignorance. Thank you .

Comment: @Joost Can you please post it as answer ?  Or I will mark Matthieu Moy 's post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not track new files automatically by default. You need to run

```
git add <newfile>
```

on each new files. `git status` will tell you this:

```
$ git status
[...]
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        foo.txt
```

If files are not shown in the `Untracked files` section of `git status`, they are probably ignored by one of your `.gitignore` files.